# Why is Buffer not a subclass of IndexedSeq?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In the scala collections library `Buffer` inherits from `Seq`:

```
Buffer[A] extends Seq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Buffer] with BufferLike[A, Buffer[A]] with scala.Cloneable
```

and the `Buffer` documentation says:

> Buffers are used to create sequences of elements incrementally by
>   appending, prepending, or inserting new elements. It is also possible
>   to access and modify elements in a **random access** fashion via the index
>   of the element in the current sequence.

while the `IndexedSeq` docs says:

> A base trait for indexed sequences.
>
> Indexed sequences support constant-time or near constant-time element
>   access and length computation. They are defined in terms of abstract
>   methods apply for indexing and length.
>
> Indexed sequences do not add any new methods to Seq, but promise
>   efficient implementations of random access patterns.

Since `Buffer` already extends `Seq` and `IndexedSeq` does not add any methods to `Seq`
Buffer must already implement the `IndexedSeq` interface and according to the documentation
it should meet the non-functional requirements of `IndexedSeq`.
So why is `Buffer` not an `IndexedSeq`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Buffer` is not `IndexedSeq` because it does not guarantee near constant-time element access and length computation. For example, `ListBuffer` supports neither, as you can see in this [description of the performance characteristics of Scala collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Comment: Ok, but the [documentation for Buffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html) says _It is also possible to access and modify elements in a random access fashion_ which seems misleading then. I had originally conflated Bufffer & ArrayBuffer in my mind

Comment: @DanielMahler It *is* also possible to access and modify at random on all `Buffer`, but not necessarily efficient. `IndexedSeq` is giving an efficiency guarantee.

Comment: My understanding is that _random access_ means efficient indexed access ie I do not think linked lists are random access. Otherwise you could randomly access into a sequential file as well. FWIW [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) also seems to take this reading. I get your answer though; I just think the documentation on `Buffer` is should be changed.